# Linuxdeployqt, appimage created successfully, doesn't run on double click

Tags: qt, deployment, qt5.9

i have created an app with the help of following command on terminal

```
./linuxdeployqt-7-x86_64.AppImage processorder/Process_Orders -unsupported-allow-new-glibc -appimage
```

An app is generated successfully. But, when i double clikc it or (right click -> run) , nothing happens,
I tried to run it using terminal.
This is what i got on terminal

```
./Process_Orders-x86_64.AppImage: symbol lookup error: ./Process_Orders-x86_64.AppImage: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5
```

Can anybody help me deploy the app successfully and run it properly?

Answer (score 0):

is seem that there are two versions of qt on your computer and you must send to appimage command the true qt address by adding -qmake option to them, like this:

```
-qmake=/opt/Qt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```